# Truncating variable text string

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm assigning the `Get-Mailbox` command to a variable so that I can output this to a log file:

```
$SmtpForwardingAddress = Get-Mailbox -Identity $Upn | Select ForwardingSmtpAddress
"Email forwarding set to $($SmtpForwardingAddress)" | Tee-Object $logfilepath -Append
```

The variable `$SmtpForwardingAddress` returns:

> "Email forwarding set to @{ForwardingSmtpAddress=smtp:Username@domain.com}"

I'd like to trim this to just the `username@domain.com` value. I've tried a couple of things but get errors like the below:

> Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'substring'.
>
> Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'Trim'.

Any ideas as to what I can do to get the desired result?

Comment: What is the output for `$SmtpForwardingAddress`?

Comment: As shown above: "@{ForwardingSmtpAddress=smtp:Username@domain.com}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object is being stored into `$SmtpForwardingAddress` instead of a `[String]` like you're expecting which does not have those methods.

Try this:

```
"Email forwarding set to $(($SmtpForwardingAddress.ForwardingSmtpAddress).TrimStart('smtp:'))
```

Comment: Ah spot on thanks. So because it's an object that's being stored, the property .ForwardingSmtpAddress needs to be added to provide the trim method with something to work with?

Comment: I'm *assuming* the object's property points to a string that is `smtp:Username@domain.com`.  You can confirm for certain by using the `.GetType()` method.  `@{}` indicates a PowerShell object.  `@()` is an array, for example.

Comment: Yes, $SmtpForwardingAddress.GetType() returns PSCustomObject whereas $SmtpForwardingAddress.ForwardingSmtpAddress.GetType() returns string. Good to know thanks

Comment: @jshizzle additionally, you can pipe an object to Get-Member to see all of its properties and methods.  Because `.ForwardingSmtpAddress` is a string, it contains the .Trim* and .Substring methods.  e.g. `$SmtpForwardingAddress.ForwardingSmtpAddress | Get-Member`

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell there always is more than one solution.

```
$ForwardingAddress = (Get-Mailbox -Identity $Upn).ForwardingSmtpAddress.Split(':')[1]
"Email forwarding set to $ForwardingAddress" | Tee-Object $logfilepath -Append
```

Comment: Nice one thanks although this doesn't like the .[1] at the end. leaving this out splits the results on three separate lines but obviously just want the one which I dare say is what the .[1] was meant to do?

Comment: Cracking stuff. Always nice to have an alternative.